# Confusion over grid and block dimensions

Tags: cuda

I am trying to solve the problem at the end of lesson 1 of the [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs344/l-55120467/e-96706674/m-63865774) course but I'm not sure if I have just made a typo or if the actual code is wrong.

```
void your_rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4 * const h_rgbaImage, uchar4 * const d_rgbaImage, unsigned char* const d_greyImage, size_t numRows, size_t numCols)
{
    size_t totalPixels = numRows * numCols;
    size_t gridRows = totalPixels / 32;
    size_t gridCols = totalPixels / 32;
    const dim3 blockSize(32,32,1);
    const dim3 gridSize(gridCols,gridRows,1);
    rgba_to_greyscale<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_rgbaImage, d_greyImage, numRows, numCols);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

The other method is:

```
void rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4* const rgbaImage, unsigned char* const greyImage, int numRows, int numCols)
{   
    int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;
    uchar4 rgba = rgbaImage[x * numCols + y];
    float channelSum = 0.299f * rgba.x + 0.587f * rgba.y + 0.114f * rgba.z;
    greyImage[x * numCols + y] = channelSum;
}
```

Error message says the following:

```
libdc1394 error: failed to initialize libdc1394
Cuda error at student_func.cu:76
unspecified launch failure cudaGetLastError()
we were unable to execute your code. Did you set the grid and/or block size correctly?
```

But then, it says that the code has compiled,

```
Your code compiled!
error output: libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Cuda error at student_func.cu:76
unspecified launch failure cudaGetLastError()
```

Line 76 is the last line in the first code block and as far as I'm aware I haven't changed anything in it. Line 76 is as follows,

```
rgba_to_greyscale<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_rgbaImage, d_greyImage, numRows, numCols);
```

I can't actually find the declaration of `cudaGetLastError()`.

I'm mainly concerned with my understanding on setting up the grid/block dimensions + whether the first methods approach was right with regards to mapping between a 1D array of pixel positions and my threads.

**EDIT:**
I guess I've misunderstood something. Is `numRows` the number of pixels in the vertical? And is `numCols` the pixels in horizontal direction?

My block is made up of 8 x 8 threads, where each thread represents 1 pixel? If so, I'm assuming that's why I had to divide by 4 when calculating `gridRows` since the image is not square? I'm assuming I could have also made a block that was 2:1 columns : rows?

[image: Screen shot]

**EDIT 2:**
I just tried to change my block so that it was 2:1 ratio, so I could then divide `numRows` and `numCol` by the same number but its now showing blank areas at the bottom and side. Why is there blank areas both at the bottom and side. I haven't changed the y dimensions of by grid or block.

[image]

Comment: there is one more error in the kernel, see answer.
also you do not need to divide by different numbers or you will cover some pixels twice or will miss some

Answer (score 10, accepted):

each blocks processes 32*32 pixels, and there are (totalPixels / 32) * (totalPixels / 32) blocks, so you process totalPixels ^ 2 pixels - that seems wrong

1st was wrong, this should be the correct one:

```
const dim3 blockSize(32,32,1);

size_t gridCols = (numCols + blockSize.x - 1) / blockSize.x;
size_t gridRows = (numRows + blockSize.y - 1) / blockSize.y;
```

it is a pretty common pattern for 2d - you can remember it

in the sample image size is not power of two and you want block to cover all your image(or even more)

so next must be correct:
gridCols * blockSize.x >= numCols
gridRows * blockSize.y >= numRows

you choose block size and basing on it you compute amount of blocks you need to cover all image

after that, in the kernel, you must check that you are not 'out of image', for cases with bad size

another problem is in the kernel, it must be (y * numCols + x), not oposite

kernel:

```
int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

if(x < numCols && y < numRows)
{
    uchar4 rgba = rgbaImage[y * numCols + x];
    float channelSum = 0.299f * rgba.x + 0.587f * rgba.y + 0.114f * rgba.z;
    greyImage[y * numCols + x] = channelSum;
}
```

calling code:

```
const dim3 blockSize(4,32,1); // may be any

size_t gridCols = (numCols + blockSize.x - 1) / blockSize.x;
size_t gridRows = (numRows + blockSize.y - 1) / blockSize.y;

const dim3 gridSize(gridCols,gridRows,1);
rgba_to_greyscale<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_rgbaImage, d_greyImage, numRows, numCols);
cudaDeviceSynchronize(); 
checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
```

damn it, i feel like i am doing things even harder to understand (

Comment: yeah ur right about the fact that my gridrows and gridcols are wrong, thanks for that. Why do u + 1 to the gridRows and gridCols?

Comment: Yeah ok, so i was just lucky that those parameters fit. I think i understand now, its quite tidy assigning more threads than pixels and then just making sure the current thread is within the range of the pixels. I had wondered what to do if the picture wasnt an exact fit for blocks of 32. One final question, when declaring the dim3 for block and grid, is it always x,y,z where x = horizontal etc? Thanks again for your help +1 :)

Comment: not sure what are you asking )
it always has 3 coordinates, but it has no real bindings to beeing 'horizontal' or 'vertical'.
It is just easier to imagine them like beeing usual x y z dims, but nothing prevents you from using 'y' or 'z' coordinate to index rows or columns or whatever

Comment: Aye ok, was just checking. Thanks again :)